# 'QScopedPointer' file not found when building with cmake

Tags: qt, cmake

I'm new to cmake and I wanted to make a basic widget that uses QScopedPointer, here's what I have in my cmakelists:

```
find_package(Qt6 6.2 COMPONENTS Quick REQUIRED)    
find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(appIndicatorWidget
    PRIVATE Qt::Quick
    PRIVATE Qt::Core
)
```

But when I try to

```
#include <QScopedPointer>
```

in any of my header files, I get the " 'QScopedPointer' file not found " error. Am I doing something wrong? Because with qmake using `QT += core` everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Qt::Quick and Qt::Core is wrong - it should be Qt6::Quick and Qt6::Core since you search for Qt6, not Qt

Comment: @chehrlic it's actually stated in official documentation that using Qt:: instead of Qt6:: or Qt5:: is in no way wrong, and changing it to Qt6:: doesn't solve my issue anyways.

Comment: is the problem with just `QScopedPointer`? and could you post your full cmakelists file and every error you get?

Answer (score 1):

According to the QScopedPointer documentation, you should add

```
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core) 
target_link_libraries(appIndicatorWidget PRIVATE Qt6::Core)
```

into your `CMAKELIST.txt` file, instead of

```
find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(appIndicatorWidget
    PRIVATE Qt::Core
)
```